# Feature request for close reasoning?

Tags: feature-request, support, meta, closed-questions

I asked question (on meta) on why a post was closed, because it made no sense, and that post was closed as well?

...a member for 11 years on Server Fault, so been here a long time and this makes no sense to me?

Can we get a comment box for the mods or bots closing that provides something a little more detailed than a link that says read this. Required that when a post is closed, there is something helpful to the poster to indicate why other than links to the help site?

OR at least request if requests for such reasoning keep getting bluntly closed, maybe an "explain please" button so the user has some chance of getting it correct the next time?

Answer (score 13):

You're talking about [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389494/explanation-of-closed-posts); it wasn't *closed* (well, technically it was - it can't receive answers anymore here), it was *migrated* to Meta Server Fault, since it related to a specific question on a single site (which apparently got deleted; I can't find it). It now lives here: [Explanation of closed posts](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9874/283889) (you should have got a message about that) and everyone but ♦ moderators here, you (apparently, I didn't know) and [users fiddling with the URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389494/?noredirect=1) will automatically be redirected. It's still open to everybody to answer.

We get questions like that from time to time; that's just the nature of this site, and we don't mind migrating those questions to the right place for them. Even though the 'Feedback' link in the footer, and the Meta **** link in the hamburger menu accessible from the rightmost icon in the topbar link to the site's own Meta, users still end up here from time to time.

Comment: If you follow the migration it says that was closed too for "Not suitable for this site", I have been a stack-overflow member for 11 years, and the original post spawning that question being closed, I have no idea why or how to find out? The whole process is confusing at best, seemingly rude overall. Other than trial and error how are people supposed to navigate this better vs getting frustrated and leaving?

Comment: Apologies, that was you moving it, it later reads "Post Locked by Community [Bot]" so still no idea why anywhere in that chain, I am seeking help and getting shut down.

Comment: @Sabre The post is not closed on [Meta Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9874/explanation-of-closed-posts), where it was migrated to. The migration reason is given in Glorfindel's answer: " it related to a specific question on a single site". Note that this site (Meta *Stack Exchange*) is for issues relating to multiple sites or the network as a whole. Anything specific to a single site is best handled by that site.

Comment: @Sabre When a question is migrated to another site, it's closed on the original site. Otherwise it would've been a copy instead of a migration. [This question of yours](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9874/explanation-of-closed-posts) is not closed on ServerFault meta.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense, just was not immediately evident. Stack exchange is a huge place, and not always the easiest to navigate.  And I know that makes maintenance a time consuming task, also individual discussions on every post closing would be a drain on that. But a post could be possibly quarantined or something until someone DID have time to add something constructive? We answer others questions, we could just as easily have a "question assistance" site where those go to live until better written? As it is now, it just feels like a slamming door and a sign that reads try harder.

Comment: @Sabre if you're upset about the question being migrated, please don't see it as being closed so much as being moved. If you're upset about your Server Fault question being closed, that's a topic for Server Fault meta.

Comment: Its not really upset, as much as complete misunderstanding on how to proceed. At least this part makes better sense now. The other is still bewildering however. I would love to fix the question because I still need an answer, how to even begin to do that though I beyond what I can glean from the vague information provided through the lock/close process of it. So thank you both for at least explaining this one :-)

Comment: And that's the reason why it is bad idea to migrate such questions. It just cause more confusion. Close and deletion banners are more clear. I know the goal is good, but only few people would understand that.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard it's less work (for moderators) to migrate than posting a comment and using the "Relates to only one specific network site" close reason :)

Comment: @Glorfindel: It seems that the post has been moved to the wrong website, looks like it was a Stack Overflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76345169/text-of-desktop-icons-on-windows. :)

Comment: @AugustoVasques no. OP clearly says it's about Server Fault, not Stack Overflow, and this post is about migrating the question they asked here, on this very site.

Comment: @Glorfindel no need for comment, close banner says everything that is needed. Comments are more needed when deleting, IMO.

Comment: Agreed, and why I started commenting on meta, perhaps the wrong meta, lesson learned, but the complain was really centric to the "deleted", the migration wording was just a misunderstanding. Problem was and still is, a post that is clearly programming assistance related, not malicious, locked and aske for more information with just a link, read the link, followed instruction, and post deleted without any meaningful explanation whatsoever on how to fix/avoid. Its a poor sense of any community, and what will drive people to bots answering questions vs egos ruling over forums. Opposite of help...